# How do you return a regex submatched group whilst ignoring spaces?

Tags: regex, vba

I am looking for some assistance with a regex.

The data I have are groups of 5 numbers separated by a comma.  So, there could be data like this:

A single group without commas: `12345`.

Any number of groups:

```
12345,54321,56789,09876
12345,54321,56789
```

Or containing some spaces:

```
" 12345 , 54321 , 56789 , 09876 "
"12345 , 54321 , 56789 , 09876"
```

But they will always be numeric and always comma delimited.

What I need is a regex which will return a single match for the whole pattern than a group for each of the delimited group but I want to ignore the whitespace.

Using this string:

```
" 12345 , 54321 , 56789 , 09876 "
```

and this pattern, I have managed to get this far:

```
^(\s*\d{5})(?:\s*,\s*(\d{5})\s*)*$
```

But this returns:

```
Full match      " 12345 , 54321 , 56789 , 09876 "  
Group 1.        " 12345"  
Group 2.        "09876"
```

The problem here is that the spaces are still in the full and group 1 match(s).  There are also the middle two groups missing.

However it should be returning this:

```
Full match      "12345,54321,56789,09876"     
Group 1.        "12345"  
Group 2.        "54321"  
Group 3.        "56789"  
Group 4.        "09876"
```

All spaces ignored and the additional two groups.

If someone could assist with the regex pattern it would be appreciated.

Ultimately I am looking for a regex pattern which is compatible with VBA as this is where it'll end up being used.

Comment: What exactly is the problem, why do you want to put the numbers into groups? Why not just use `\d+` and use `.Global=True` / `.Execute`?

Comment: I want the number in to groups as this facilitates processing later on.  The full match will be used to indicate I have the correct overall format and the sub groups will be iterated over later on and processed. `\d+` does appear to return lots of groups but does not return the full match.

Comment: Ok, so that is what you can do: 1) check the format with your regex, 2) once it matches, split with `,` and trim the whitespace from all the resulting array items. There is no way to keep all captures with repeated capturing groups.

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: @Sweeper initially https://regex101.com/ in order try and get the regex pattern but ultimately this will end up in VBA.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew was trying to do this in one step but was not aware that this was not possible - can only hope :)  but if there is no way then looks like a manual split with trim is necessary!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBA regex does not allow storing all captured values matched with a [repeated capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html).

You may validate your strings with the regex you have (you may remove capturing groups to make it leaner) and then, upon a match, get an array of values by splitting the string with a comma and then iterate over the array to trim all whitespace and put the values into a collection.

Here is an example in VBA:

```
Dim reg As RegExp
Dim ms As MatchCollection
Dim coll As Collection
Dim tmpArr As Variant

Dim s As String

s = " 12345 , 54321 , 56789 , 09876 "
Set reg = New RegExp
Set coll = New Collection
With reg
  .Pattern = "^\s*\d{5}(?:\s*,\s*\d{5})*\s*$"
End With

Set ms = reg.Execute(s)     ' Search for a match
If ms.Count > 0 Then        ' There is match
  tmpArr = Split(s, ",")    ' Split with comma
  For Each i In tmpArr      ' Iterate over the array
    coll.Add (Trim(i))      ' Trim each item
  Next i
End If
```

[image]

Comment: How to iterate through that colllection to retrieve the added values? Thanks for this awesome script @Wiktor Stribiżew. Provided plus one.

Comment: @Topto Do you mean how to iterate a collection? `For Each elt In coll` > `Debug.Print elt` > `Next` (`>` is a line break).

Comment: Thanks for the clarity. I also figured it like `For K = 1 To coll.Count: MsgBox coll.Item(K): Next K`.