# How to remove line feed?

Tags: excel, regex, vba, outlook

This script for Outlook returns the desired date but doesn't remove the line feed.

String I want to get the date from:
1_c Anruf/Meldung am (Datum): 04.Mai.2020

```vb
With Reg1
    .Pattern = "1_c Anruf\/Meldung am \(Datum\)\s*[:]+\s*(.*)\s+\n"
    .Global = False
End With
If Reg1.Test(olMail.Body) Then
    Set M1 = Reg1.Execute(olMail.Body)
End If
For Each M In M1
    Debug.Print M.SubMatches(0)
    With xExcelApp
        Range("A5").Value = M.SubMatches(0)
    End With
Next M
```

regex101 selects correctly but the debugger always shows something like "02.12.2020 ". <- containing no whitespace but a line feed.

In Excel the line feed is also visible. Also trailing whitespace isn't a problem since I can use TRIM but the line feed doesn't allow it to function.

Comment: Try `1_c Anruf/Meldung am \(Datum\)\s*:+\s*([^\r\n]*)` (the forward slash does not have to be escaped in the VBA code).

Comment: Nice, that works! Only thing is apparently you have to remove the white space at the end too because trim only does its thing after clicking in an excel cell. Could you help me with the implementation of that too?

Comment: Yes, you need to add `\S` at the end of the capturing group to make sure you stop matching after reaching the last non-whitespace char on the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex captures the CR symbol, you can replace `.` with `[^\r\n]` to avoid this behavior.

It seems you want to use

```js
1_c Anruf/Meldung am \(Datum\)\s*:+\s*([^\r\n]*\S)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mnGwDL/1/). Note the forward slash does not have to be escaped in the VBA code. *Details*:

- `1_c Anruf/Meldung am \(Datum\)` - a fixed `1_c Anruf/Meldung am (Datum)` string
- `\s*:+\s*` - one or more colons enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
- `([^\r\n]*\S)` - Capturing group  1 (accessed with `M.SubMatches(0)`) that captures zero or more occurrences of any char other than CR and LF chars and then any non-whitespace char.

Comment: **Excellent**, works well! Only thing is that Excel still only converts the date after opening the cell but that's not part of the code so it would be a different problem.

Comment: @NotPaul Right, maybe `ActiveSheet.Calculate` will help.

Comment: Yeah could but I just used `CDate` and `Format` to only show the month.

Comment: @NotPaul To get individual fields between commas, use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51234361/3832970) to split and trim the `M.SubMatches(0)` value.