# Match n amount of words separated by commas after base text

Tags: regex, vba

I would like to match an infinite amount of words separated by commas and whitespaces.

Is there a better solution than just repeating the search parameter?

Sample:

```
"2_i Art des Problems:\s*(.[^,\s]+)[,]\s*(.[^,\s]+)[,]\s*(.[^,\s]+)"
```

```
2_i Art des Problems: Elektrisch, Schweißausrüstung, Burgenland
```

View on regex101: https://regex101.com/r/yP7PPO/1

Full code for this operation:

```
With Reg1
.Pattern = "2_i Art des Problems:+\s*([^\r\n]*\S)"
.Global = False
End With
If Reg1.Test(olMail.Body) Then
    Set M1 = Reg1.Execute(olMail.Body)
End If
For Each M In M1
    With xExcelApp
        Select Case M.SubMatches
            Case Software
                Range("D6").Value = 1
            Case Mechanisch
                Range("E6").Value = 1
            Case Elektrisch
                Range("F6").Value = 1
            Case Roboter
                Range("G6").Value = 1
            Case Schweißausrüstung
                Range("H6").Value = 1
            Case Anwendung
                Range("I6").Value = 1
            Case Ersatzteil
                Range("J6").Value = 1
            Case Else
                Range("K6").Value = 1
        End Select
    End With
Next M
```

Comment: You can use a single capture group and split on `, `

Comment: So, do you want returning "Elektrisch, Schweißausrüstung, Burgenland"? If yes, in which way? What the above string means against the second one? Can you show the real string to be processed? Do you mean the strings following the ":" character?

Comment: If you do not show your whole code, the string to be processed against the needed one, how to receive any help? What should "just repeating the search parameter" mean in your question context?

Comment: @FaneDuru I want the individual words as match groups just like in the regex101 link I added but without having to repeat the `[,]\s*(.[^,\s]+)`.

Comment: Do you want them in an array, in a string like the example, but eliminating the part until ":" inclusively? Place them in an Excel row/column? Where from the big strings to be taken from, how and where the processing result to be returned...? Can you show another string, too? In your string not the comma is the separator. It is ", " (two characters), which is something else...

Comment: "to repeat the `[,]\s*(.[^,\s]+)`" against what? Do you have some rows in a file/workbook to be processed? A big string containing many lines, consecutive strings supplied by an application, or what?

Comment: You cannot *capture* unlimited times within the same group in VBA regex. You need to match the whole thing with `2_i Art des Problems:\s*(.+)`, then split with `", "`. Or with `,`, then trim the results if necessary.

Comment: Maybe this post is a dupe of [How do you return a regex submatched group whilst ignoring spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51234107/how-do-you-return-a-regex-submatched-group-whilst-ignoring-spaces/51234361#51234361)

Comment: @FaneDuru I want it to only capture the words as separate capture groups, eliminating everything else so I can use them in an `For Each group in match` and `Select Case` (e.g. Elektrisch) and therefore assign the Elektrisch cell a value.

Comment: Can you edit your question and show us your code attempt to do what you try asking in words? Maybe we will better understand looking to the code and you may also receive some solutions for the code itself. Your question is too general and I still cannot understand what is it and how to be returned, in ofer to be useful. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)... [Minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)...

Comment: @FaneDuru I added the full code for this problem, hope it helps.

Comment: You did not show all the used code... Anyhow, you need to extract the string(s) to be processed from an email body. I (only) suppose that there are many rows to be processed. In terms of `String`, each line has a end separator, which has to be eliminated. Now, do you wan to process **each body line** or everything at once? Then, in order to work, you need to put the strings to be checked between double quotes: `Case "Software"` and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it really need to be a RegEx?

I think this is over complicating things as this can easily be solved with `Split()`:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Example()
    Const TestString As String = "2_i Art des Problems: Elektrisch, Schweißausrüstung, Burgenland"
    Const ConstantPart As String = "2_i Art des Problems: "
    
    If Left$(TestString, Len(ConstantPart)) = ConstantPart Then
        Dim Parts() As String
        Parts = Split(Mid$(TestString, Len(ConstantPart) + 1), ", ")
        
        Dim Part As Variant
        For Each Part In Parts
            Debug.Print Part
        Next Part
    End If
End Sub
```

Output is:

```
Elektrisch
Schweißausrüstung
Burgenland
```

Comment: This works! I changed it so the `TestString` is the return of the regex search:
`(2_i Art des Problems\s*[:]+\s*([^\r\n]*\S)`
and used the `Select Case` to filter the results.

Answer (score 1):

If you realy need to use regexp than use global flag and e.g. this regexp

```
(.[^,\s]+)(,|$)
```

Explanation [here](https://regex101.com/r/Hdj24v/1)

```
        With regEx
        .Global = True
```

Use `.SubMatches` to get capturing groups values

EDIT:
according to one of comment "Then you still need to Trim the matches because they will include the spaces. – Pᴇʜ 1 min ago"

you can still use regexp

```
.([^,\s]+)(,|$)
```

[check](https://regex101.com/r/ufUWtf/1)

Comment: Then you still need to `Trim` the matches because they will include the spaces.

Comment: So use this one :) .([^,\s]+)(,|$)